Preview from Open Graph is not appearing in Telegram for main page
I'm encountering an issue where the preview from Open Graph is not appearing in Telegram for the main page of my website, but it appears for any other page. For example:
https://andrei-psyhelp.ru/ - Preview is not working
https://andrei-psyhelp.ru/consent - Preview is working
Both pages have identical meta information.
I've ensured that the meta tags for title, description, and image are properly set on the main page, yet Telegram seems to be ignoring them. Is there any specific reason why Telegram might not be displaying the Open Graph preview for the main page? Are there any additional steps or considerations I should take to ensure the preview appears correctly?

You have the same values in the head section for og:url and the canonical addresses, which could be messing up Telegram. Each page should have its own, unique values. Once you provide unique values, try clearing Telegram’s cache using @webpagebot, although some people say the bot no longer works, and see what happens.

Please try putting
'<link rel="preload" as="image" href="/header.avif" type="image/avif"/>'

all preload image tags after meta tags.
